# Speed up Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have my class structure as follows

```
public class Email 
{
    public string Subject {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public Contact Sender {get;set;}
    public string SenderEmail {get;set;}
}
public class Contact
{
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and I run my Linq query in two parts
First i select all the emails.

```
var query = from msg in context.Email
            select msg;
```

Then i assign the Contact details to the Email Class

```
List<Email> outputList = new List<Email>();
foreach (var item in query.ToList())
{
    var q = from contact in context.Contact
            where contact.Email = item.SenderEmail
            select contact;
    item.Sender = q.SingleOrDefault();
    outputList.Add(item);
}


return outputList;
```

Is there anyway i can run a join query and simply output the List without having to run multiple queries

Comment: Why do so many people write something completely redundant like `from msg in context.Email select msg` instead of just `context.Email` and then complain that it’s slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do the trick (warning: untested code):

```
    var qry = from email in context.Email
              join contact in context.Contact 
              on email.SenderEmail equals contact.Email
              into contacts
              select new { eml = email, sender = contacts.FirstOrDefault() };

    var items = qry.ToList();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        item.eml.Sender = item.sender;
        outputList.Add(item.eml);
    }

    return outputList;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this should work:

```
var query = from msg in context.Email
            join contact in context.Contact 
                 on msg.SenderEmail equals contact.Email
                 into contacts
            select new { msg, contacts };

var list = query.ToList();
foreach (var pair in list)
{
    pair.msg.Sender = pair.contacts.FirstOrDefault();
}

var messages = list.Select(pair => pair.msg);
```

This uses a group join. You haven't said which LINQ provider you're using, but I expect it should work for most providers...

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it, but I have to say I'm pretty elated to have come up with code this close to something Jon Skeet wrote. :)

Comment: @Justin: Note that you need to use a group join in case the sender email doesn't match any contacts, or matches multiple contacts.

Comment: Good point. Edited mine to take that into account, and +1 to yours.